# Github private repository settings access for collaborators

Tags: security, github

Is it possible to give a collaborator access to the settings of a private repositrory? If I am the owner of a repository I have a link in the top-right corner of my repository in the browser, however if I am a collaborator and somebody else owns the repository I do not have this link. Is it possible for the owner of a repository to give a collaborator access to the settings of a repository and how would you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Settings access is available to administrators of a repository.  If the owner of a repository is a human, they will have access as well, and the administrators of an organization will if the owner of the repository is an organization.

The owner can grant you access to the settings functionality by making you an administrator, either by putting you on a team with administrator permissions for that repo or granting you those permissions explicitly on the repository.